# KOMAscript: How to 'flush bottom' part title page's preamble?

Tags: sectioning, vertical-alignment, koma-script, parts

**Context:** I am using the `scrbook` class. Part titles are printed on an empty page, and then the next content starts on a new page.
KOMAscript however provides the `\setpartpreamble[<position>]{<text>}` command that enables to print some text on the part title page. `<position>` is either `o` to insert text above the heading, or `u` for inserting text below.

The documentation tells explicitly:

> Please note that it is *you* who is responsible for the spaces between the heading, preamble and the following text.

**Problem:** I want to "flush bottom" a preable inserted below the heading (the latter is top-aligned). However, I had no success either in inserting a `\vspace*{\fill}` at the beginning of the preamble text, or in modifying sthe space below the part heading as follow `\renewcommand{\partheadendvskip}{\vskip\fill\newpage}`. (I imagine that "*it is you who is responsible for the spaces between the heading, and preamble*" means "`\partheadendvskip` will not be taken into consideration when a preable is added")

**Question:** How to bottom align the preamble on a part title page in `scrbook`?

---

[image]

```
\documentclass[open any]{scrbook}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \usepackage{showframe}

    \renewcommand{\partheadstartvskip}{\null}% removes vertical space before part title
    \renewcommand{\partheadendvskip}{\vskip\fill\newpage}% no effect
\begin{document}
    \setpartpreamble[u]{
        %\vspace*{\fill}% <-- has no effet
        This text comes after the part title, but on the same page.
        I would like to ``flushbottom'' it, i.e.\@ I want it to be aligned with the bottom of the text area.
    }
    \part{Part title}
    \lipsum
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The content of the part preamble is set in a `\parbox`, so flush bottom it seems to be not possible.

Maybe you are using `scrlayer-scrpage` for header and footer? Then you can define a new page style for part pages and insert your preamble using a new layer added to this page style.

```
\documentclass[open=any]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{showframe}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=0pt
]{part}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\DeclareNewLayer[
  textarea,
  foreground,
  contents=\vfill\mypartpreamble
]{partpreamble}
\DeclareNewPageStyleByLayers{partpage}{partpreamble}
\ForEachLayerOfPageStyle{plain.scrheadings}{%
    \AddLayersToPageStyle{partpage}{#1}%
}
\renewcommand\partpagestyle{partpage}

\makeatother
\newcommand\mypartpreamble{}
\newcommand\setmypartpreamble[1]{\def\mypartpreamble{#1}}
\xapptocmd{\partheademptypage}{\setmypartpreamble{}}{}{}

\begin{document}
    \part{Part title without Preamble}
    \lipsum

    \setmypartpreamble{
        This text comes after the part title, but on the same page.
        I would like to ``flushbottom'' it, i.e.\@ I want it to be aligned with the bottom of the text area.
    }
    \part{Part title with Preamble}
    \lipsum

    \part{Part tile without Preamble}
    \lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Package `scrlayer-scrpage` is based on package `scrlayer`.

It is also possible to use only package `scrlayer` for the special page style on part pages. Then it could be that you have to declare an additional layer for the page number.

Example without any other package for header and footer, but with `\pagestyle{headings}`:

```latex
\documentclass[open=any,footlines=1]{scrbook}
%\providecommand*\Ifthispageodd{\ifthispageodd}% needed up to and including KOMA-Script version 3.27, see https://komascript.de/faq_deprecatedif
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{showframe}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=0pt
]{part}

\pagestyle{headings}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{scrlayer}
\DeclareNewLayer[
  textarea,
  foreground,
  contents=\vfill\mypartpreamble
]{partpreamble}
\DeclareNewLayer[
  foot,
  background,
  contents={\Ifthispageodd{\hfill\pagemark}{\pagemark\hfill}}
]{partpagenumber}
\DeclareNewPageStyleByLayers{partpage}{partpreamble,partpagenumber}
\renewcommand\partpagestyle{partpage}

\makeatother
\newcommand\mypartpreamble{}
\newcommand\setmypartpreamble[1]{\def\mypartpreamble{#1}}
\xapptocmd{\partheademptypage}{\setmypartpreamble{}}{}{}

\begin{document}
    \part{Part title without Preamble}
    \lipsum

    \setmypartpreamble{
        This text comes after the part title, but on the same page.
        I would like to ``flushbottom'' it, i.e.\@ I want it to be aligned with the bottom of the text area.
    }
    \part{Part title with Preamble}
    \lipsum

    \part{Part tile without Preamble}
    \lipsum
\end{document}
```

Or with package `fancyhdr` and a centered page number:

```
\documentclass[open=any,footlines=1]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{showframe}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=0pt
]{part}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{scrlayer}
\DeclareNewLayer[
  textarea,
  foreground,
  contents=\vfill\mypartpreamble
]{partpreamble}
\DeclareNewLayer[
  foot,
  background,
  contents={\hfill\pagemark\hfill}
]{partpagenumber}
\DeclareNewPageStyleByLayers{partpage}{partpreamble,partpagenumber}
\renewcommand\partpagestyle{partpage}

\makeatother
\newcommand\mypartpreamble{}
\newcommand\setmypartpreamble[1]{\def\mypartpreamble{#1}}
\xapptocmd{\partheademptypage}{\setmypartpreamble{}}{}{}

\begin{document}
    \part{Part title without Preamble}
    \lipsum

    \setmypartpreamble{
        This text comes after the part title, but on the same page.
        I would like to ``flushbottom'' it, i.e.\@ I want it to be aligned with the bottom of the text area.
    }
    \part{Part title with Preamble}
    \lipsum

    \part{Part tile without Preamble}
    \lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, it's clever! I am not that fluent with layers, so thank you for giving me a chance to work on it!